# Bool function in Python for text based adventure

Tags: python, text, path, boolean, adventure

Ok, so I am trying to set a bool so that if an item is taken it becomes True and next time if it is True then it takes a different path, it's my first time writing something in Python so excuse the bad code conventions. Anyways, I need the bool to be False until the note is taken, and when it is I want it to become True. One problem I will probably have in the future is that in one part the player comes back to this room, how can I keep the bool True for when they do?

```
def first_room(Note):
    choice1_1 = raw_input('The house looks much larger than it did from the outside. You appear in a room, to your left is a closet, to your right is a pile of junk, in front of you is a door, and behind you is the exit.')
    choice1_1 = choice1_1.lower()
    if choice1_1 == 'left' or choice1_1 == 'l' or choice1_1 == 'closet':
        if note == False:
            choice1_c = raw_input('You open the closet and check inside, there is a note. Do you take the note? (Y/N)')
            choice1_c = choice1_c.lower()
            if choice1_c == 'y':
                print 'You took the note.'
                first_room(True)
            if choice1_c == 'n':
                print 'You leave the note alone.'
                first_room(False)
        else:
            print 'The closet is empty.'
            first_room(True)
first_room(False)
```

Comment: Case matters in Python. `def first_room(Note)` and `def first_room(note)` are not the same thing.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use function calls as GOTO's. This is a bad idea because it won't work the way you want/expect it to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  I've tidied up the indentation of the code for you (avoid tabs on SO; they cause trouble).  The only line I'm not sure about is the very last one, the `first_room(False)`.  It might be meant to be part of the function or it might be a separate statement after the function (or it might be intended to come after an `else:` for the first `if`).  Please edit the function if I chose the wrong indentation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, pretty sure the last line should be dedented

Comment: @gnibbler: given the OP's edit, it appears you were correct.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here:

First, you formulate your question assuming the whole world is familiar with the context you are working in. Well, we aren't. :-) Somehow it looks like you want the function to remember the value of `note`, but I am not sure.

More problems:

```
def first_room(Note):
```

in Python, *class* names begin with uppercase, variable names should begin with lowercase.

```
if note == False:
```

Never, **ever** do this! You can test a Boolean directly, like:

```
if not note:
```

You can also swap the two arms of the `if` to make it sound less silly:

```
if note:
    # ... do something ...
else:
    # ... do something else ...
```

In any case I would recommend you attend a basic programming course...

Comment: In my situation, I can't attend a programming course. Parents won't allow it. I only started with Python yesterday and previously all I knew was some visual basic, either way thanks for the help. It works, I had just accidentally wrote Note instead of note, didn't mean to. Also, just curious about the "if not note:" thing, haven't seen that used. Does "if note:" test if it's true?

Comment: Glad that you started learning Python, it is a very nice language and will help you master general programming concepts. Apart from the official documentation, you probably know about [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net) which is an excellent introduction to the language. Last advice: don't bother with Python 3 just yet, Version 2 is fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of datastructure to store the state of the rooms. A `dict` is probably a good choice

eg:

```
rooms = {}
rooms['first_room'] = {'note': False}
```

Then you can inspect the state of the note like this

```
if rooms['first_room']['note']:
    ...
```

and update it like this

```
rooms['first_room']['note'] = True
```

At this stage of your learning, don't be afraid to make `rooms` a global variable

Comment: Was just looking at the dict concept today, still kind of hazy, taking the lessons at another site and I'm only about 5/12 of the way through. Thanks for the help!